# Getting jQuery unrecognized expression error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an HTML template that contains a jQuery function that executes an Ajax request to my web server.  The data in the response contains strings with car brand names and numbers which are used to set the value in an input checkbox for each particular car brand.  Here's an example from the template:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="list" value="2">
<label for="brand">Mercedes</label>
```

I'm trying to use the following jQuery code to see if the input checkbox is checked for each car brand.  index.name is a string and contains the car brand (e.g. "Mercedes") and index.id contains the value 2 which is a JavaScript number type (I confirmed this in the console):

```
$.each(data, function(key, index) {
    if ( $('input[type=checkbox][value=index.id]').prop('checked', true) ) {
        console.log("Checkbox is checked");
    }
});
```

When I run the jQuery code, I'm getting this error:

```
    Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[type=checkbox][value=index.id]
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?  I've read other Stackoverflow questions on how to do this and what I'm doing appears to be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to quote the parameter to an attribute selector if it contains any special characters (in this case, the `.` character):

```
 $('input[type=checkbox][value="index.id"]')
```

However, this will looks for a checkbox whose value is the literal string `index.id`. If you're actually trying to use the value of the expression `index.id`, neither way will do it, since variables aren't expanded inside strings. You need to concatenate:

```
$('input[type=checkbox][value="' + index.id+ '"]')
```

or use an ES6 template literal:

```
$(`input[type=checkbox][value="${index.id}"]`)
```

Comment: Thanks!!  That's something I didn't understand.

Comment: But one problem now is that by looking to see if the checkbox is checked, my code is actually causing an unchecked checkbox to be checked (and vice-versa).  I now need to figure out how to just read this property without altering the checkbox itself.

Comment: `.prop('checked', true)` is for setting the value of the property. To get the value of a property you use `.prop('checked')`. You can also use the `:checked` selector: `$(\`input[type=checkbox][value="${index.id}"]:checked\`)`